# Error overfull \hbox when ending document \end{document}. Linked to BibTex use in Overleaf, maybe

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, overfull

Using the following document:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\title{IIB Project: Roadmap to Zero Emissions in a Cambridge College}
\author{Candidate 5557G}

\begin{document}
...
\tableofcontents

\cite{carmichael2019behaviour}
\cite{LightsOff}
\cite{carmichael2019behaviour}
\cite{LightsOff}
\cite{carmichael2019behaviour}
\cite{LightsOff}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With bibliography named: References.bib, containing:

```
@online{LightsOff,
  author = {Utility Design},
  title = {Leaving The Lights On | A Study From Utility Design},
  year = "2018",
  url = {https://www.utilitydesign.co.uk/blog/leaving-lights-on/},
  urldate = {2022-05-26}
}

@article{carmichael2019behaviour,
  title={Behaviour change, public engagement and Net Zero},
  author={Carmichael, Richard},
  journal={A Report for the Committee on Climate Change. Available online: https://www.theccc.org. uk/publications/ and http://www.imperial.ac.uk/icept/publications/(accessed on 1 December 2019)},
  year={2019}
}
```

I get an overfull error at the end of the document. Any ideas why?[image: Image of document. Line 22 has an error]

Comment: You get an overfull hbox warning when something doesn't quite fit in the spot it goes in, and LaTeX can't find another place to move it without breaking its fussy typesetting rules. You might see something protruding into the margin in your output. You didn't post your full document including document class, etc., so I can't test it, but it's almost certainly because of the url in the bibliography. It's a warning not an error though so if it looks OK, you can ignore it. Otherwise look at the various questions here about breaking urls in bibliographies for solutions.

Comment: O frabjous day! Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I left out the \begin{document} command but you can see from the screenshot that the rest is there... Not sure how to mark your answer as the correct one but this thread is solved now.